# How to stop anacron from executing a specific missed cron job?

Tags: cron, anacron

I want my computer to shutdown at 1 a.m., but if I have already suspended it before that then the shutdown should not happen at all.

I have tried editing the crontab file, but when I resumed from suspension, anacron carried out the shutdown. Is there any way to stop anacron from doing this?

EDIT: I'm aware that I could disable anacron completely, but there are other cron jobs that requires anacron. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

Don't schedule the shutdown with `anacron`. Schedule it as a `cron` job instead.

The purpose of `anacron` is to make sure that system maintenance tasks are run on a regular basis, even if the machine is powered off for periods at a time (in which case any jobs that should have been run during the downtime will run as soon as possible once the system is back on line and `anacron` is executed).

`anacron` is not the job scheduler you'd want to run a nightly shutdown job with, or anything else that is required to run at *specific* times.

Instead, add a cronjob for root:

```
0 1 * * * /sbin/poweroff
```

(or whatever other command you may use to power off your machine)

Also make sure that `anacron` is *not* used to run the job (check the `anacrontab` file).

---

There is absolutely no issues with running both `cron` and `anacron` jobs on the same machine.  In fact, you should probably be running `anacron` from `cron`.  Just make sure that jobs handled by `cron` are not also handled by `anacron` and vice versa.

In my own crontab for root, I have the following entries that executes `anacron` on reboots and at midnight:

```
@reboot /usr/local/sbin/anacron -ds
@daily  /usr/local/sbin/anacron -ds
```

Comment: Is there anyway to schedule a job as a cron job without triggering anacron? I know that I could just disable anacron altogether, but I have other cron jobs that need anacron.

Comment: @PyGeek03 Yes, just use `crontab -e` to edit your crontab and add the job there. And make sure that anacron is not running cron's jobs.